# BASH nested redirection debug

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I know this should be easy, but the following multiple redirection just doesn't work:

```
cat testfile > ./streamCompress > ./streamDecompress
```

Both streamCompress and streamDecompress use input from stdin, and output to stdout.

This should be similar, but did not help me: [Nested Redirection in BASH](https://superuser.com/questions/488734/nested-redirection-in-bash)

Comment: The `>` operator is used to redirect output to files, not processes.

Comment: @chepner I am curious: what then supposed to be the`2` in `ls 1>2> /dev/null` *(btw, it doesn't worked)* — a file?

Answer (score 1):

If streamCompress and streamDecompress are programs that take input from stdin and send output to stdout,  you shouldn't be using ">" but "|" (pipe) instead.

Comment: Tried it, and it gives the error bash: ./streamDecompress: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Can you provide the output from "uname -a", "file streamDecompress" and "ldd -r streamDecompress"?

Comment: Need quite a bit more details of what you are trying to do, and the actors involved. And doing the command you give _will_ have destroyed streamCompress (and probably streamDecompress too).

Comment: Linux nyancat 3.8.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 29 19:18:14 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
./dzy: data
 not a dynamic executable

Comment: Vonbrand: using only stdin and stdout, pass data to be compressed via standard X, and also be able to decompress the compressed data.

Comment: Josh, looks like Vonbrand is semi-correct, it appears that you have overwritten streamDecompress with data.  My hope was that it would not have had the write permission set and it was still intact.  You will need to replace streamDecompress.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to copy the passing flow into a file use `tee(1)`:

cmd1 | tee file1 | cmd2 > file2

Comment: Not what I'm trying to do.